# argparse: How to use required positionals and subparsers together?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm encountering a simple use-case that `argparse` surprisingly doesn't seem to handle. I would like to have a required positional argument in addition to having multiple subparsers. The rationale is that this CLI application supports one use-case very readily with a concise syntax, with more granular options being nested under subcommands. For this post, imagine that I am writing a CLI application for tagging files with the syntax:

```
# tag a file
argparse_test.py <file> [<tags>...]

# list tags
argparse_test.py tags <file>
```

Usage example:

```
$ argparse_test.py ./cat.jpg cute funny
$ argparse_test.py tags ./cat.jpg
> cute, funny
```

My implementation is as follows:

```py
import argparse

# initialize main parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', help="The file to index.")
parser.add_argument('tags', nargs='*', help="Tags to append.")

# initialize `tags` subparser
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
tag_subparser = subparsers.add_parser("tags")
tag_subparser.add_argument('file', help="The file to list tags for.")

# 1. Failing test case
args = parser.parse_args(["./cat.jpg", "cute", "funny"])
print(args)

# 2. Failing test case (comment out #1 to reach this)
args = parser.parse_args(["tags", "./cat.jpg"])
print(args)
```

Surprisingly, this fails in both cases!

For the first test case:

```
usage: argparse_test.py [-h] file [tags ...] {tags} ...
argparse_test.py: error: argument {tags}: invalid choice: 'funny' (choose from 'tags')
```

For the second test case:

```
usage: argparse_test.py tags [-h] file
argparse_test.py tags: error: the following arguments are required: file
```

Commenting out either the main parser or the subparser will fix one (but not both) test case every time. It looks like this issue stems from some conflict `argparse` has in dealing with required positionals and subcommands.

**Is there any known way to implement support for this CLI syntax via `argparse` in Python 3.8+?**

(BTW, I've tested this on Python 3.9, 3.10, and 3.11, all of which share the same behavior).

Comment: think of the `subparsers` as anther `positional` with `choices`.  Also the string is assigned to the argument and then tested against the choices.

Comment: Another thought - don't try to get the same `dest` in both the main and the sub.

Comment: get rid of the `add_argument('tags', nargs='*',` argument.  a variable nargs positional creats too many headaches when also using a `subparsers` positional

Comment: i commented on a similar bug issue https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/103520 and on SO https://stackoverflow.com/q/75930563/901925

Answer (score 0):

I got two different solutions. The first one will work with your examples. The second one is what I recommend.

## First Solution

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("action")
options, remainder = parser.parse_known_args()
if options.action == "tags":
    print(f"Show tags. Files: {remainder}")
else:
    print(f"File: {options.action}")
    print(f"Tags: {remainder}")
```

Basically, I would parse the "action".

- If that action is "tags", then what follows (the remainder) is a list of files.
- Else, that action is a file, follows by a list of tags

The problem with this approach is the interface is not consistent: in one case, the first argument is a file name; in the other case, the first argument is a command.

## Second Solution

I propose another solution, which introduce two sub commands: "add-tags" and "show-tags". You can call them whatever you like.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparser = parser.add_subparsers(dest="action")

add_tags = subparser.add_parser("add-tags")
add_tags.add_argument("file")
add_tags.add_argument("tags", nargs="+")

show_tags = subparser.add_parser("show-tags")
show_tags.add_argument("file")

print("\n# Add tags")
args = parser.parse_args(["add-tags", "./cat.jpg", "cute", "funny"])
print(args)

print("\n# Show tags")
args = parser.parse_args(["show-tags", "./cat.jpg"])
print(args)
```

Output:

```
# Add tags
Namespace(action='add-tags', file='./cat.jpg', tags=['cute', 'funny'])

# Show tags
Namespace(action='show-tags', file='./cat.jpg')
```

The advantages of this approach are:

- Consistent interface: the first argument is always a command
- Extensibility: we can later add more sub commands such as "remove-tags", "clear-all-tags", ...